# MySQL Update Query, Rows Matched But Not Changed

Tags: mysql

Why will this not update 501 records?  What's wrong with my query?

```
MariaDB [contacts]> UPDATE history h, phone_corrections t SET h.contact = t.new_nmbr WHERE h.contact = t.old_nmbr;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)
Rows matched: 501  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [contacts]>
```

Answer (score 0):

FIXED!  There were several records where the `wrong_nmbr` field was the same value as the `right_nmbr` field.  Sorry for the post.